# What is Event Driven Concurrency?

Tags: scala, concurrency, event-driven

I am starting to learn Scala and functional programming. I was reading the book !Programming scala: Tackle Multi-Core Complexity on the Java Virtual Machine". Upon the first chapter I've seen the word Event-Driven concurrency and Actor model. Before I continue reading this book I want to have an idea about Event-Driven concurrency or Actor Model.

What is Event-Driven concurrency, and how is it related to Actor Model?

Comment: -1. What did you do/read so far to get an idea of what Event Driven Concurrency is? Google should at least be able to help you with that. The first three hits for me are: http://berb.github.io/diploma-thesis/original/055_events.html, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2gcrTsQ7yi4, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An Event Driven programming model involves registering code to be run when a given event fires. An example is, instead of calling a method that returns some data from a database:

```
val user = db.getUser(1)
println(user.name)
```

You could instead register a callback to be run when the data is ready:

```
db.getUser(1, u => println(u.name))
```

In the first example, no concurrency was happening; The current thread would block until `db.getUser(1)` returned data from the database. In the second example `db.getUser` would return immediately and carry on executing the next code in the program. In parallel to this, the callback `u => println(u.name)` will be executed at some point in the future.

Some people prefer the second approach as it doesn't mean memory hungry Threads are needlessly sat around waiting for slow I/O to return.

The Actor Model is an example of how Event-Driven concepts can be used to help the programmer easily write concurrent programs.

From a super high level, Actors are objects that define a series of Event Driven message handlers that get fired when the Actor receives messages. In Akka, each instance of an Actor is single Threaded, however when many of these Actors are put together they create a system with concurrency.

For example, Actor `A` could send messages to Actor `B` and `C` in parallel. Actor `B` and `C` could fire messages back to Actor `A`. Actor `A` would have message handlers to receive these messages and behave as desired.

To learn more about the Actor model I would recommend reading the Akka documentation. It is *really* well written: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/

There is also lot's of good documentation around the web about Event Driven Concurrency that us much more detailed than what I've written here. http://berb.github.io/diploma-thesis/original/055_events.html

Answer (score 3):

Theon's answer provides a good modern overview. I'd like to add some historical perspective.

Tony Hoare and Robert Milner both developed mathematical algebra for analysing concurrent systems (Communicating Sequential Processes, CSP, and Communicating Concurrent Systems, CCS). Both of these look like heavy mathematics to most of us but the practical application is relatively straightforward. CSP led directly to the Occam programming language amongst others, with Go being the newest example. CCS led to Pi calculus and the mobility of communicating channel ends, a feature that is part of Go and was added to Occam in the last decade or so.

CSP models concurrency purely by considering automomous entities ('processes', v.lightweight things like green threads) interacting simply by event exchange. The medium for passing events is along channels. Processes may have to deal with several inputs or outputs and they do this by selecting the event that is ready first. The events usually carry data from the sender to the receiver.

A principle feature of the CSP model is that a pair of processes engage in communication only when both are ready - in practical terms this leads to what is usually called 'synchronous' communication. However, the actual implementations (Go, Occam, Akka) allow channels to be buffered (the normal state in Akka) so that the lock-step exchange of events is often actually decoupled instead.

So in summary, an event-driven CSP-based system is really a data-flow network of processes connected by channels.

Besides the CSP interpretation of event-driven, there have been others. An important example is the 'event-wheel' approach, once popular for modelling concurrent systems whilst actually having a single processing thread. Such systems handle events by putting them into a processing queue and dealing with them due course, usually via a callback. Java Swing's event processing engine is a good example. There were others, e.g. for time-based simulation engines. One might think of the Javascript / NodeJS model as fitting into this category as well.

So in summary, an event-wheel was a way to express concurrency but without parallelism.

The irony of this is that the two approaches I've described above are both described as event driven but what they mean by event driven is different in each case. In one case, hardware-like entities are wired together; in the other, almost all actions are executed by callbacks. The CSP approach claims to be scalable because it's fully composable; it's naturally adept at parallel execution also. If there are any reasons to favour one over the other, these are probably it.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the answer to this you have to look at event concurrency from the OS layer up.  First you start with threads which are the smallest section of code that can be run by the OS and eventually deal with I/O, timing and other kinds of events.

The OS groups threads into a process in which they share the same memory, protection and security permissions. Above that layer you have user programs which typically make I/O requests that are handled by user libraries.

The I/O libraries handle these requests in one of two ways. Unix-like systems use a "reactor" model in which the library registers I/O handlers for all the different types of I/O and events in the system.  These handlers are activated when I/O is ready on a specific device. Windows-like systems use an I/O completion model in which I/O requests are made and a callback is triggered when the request is complete.

Both of these models require a significant amount of overhead to manage overall program state if you were to use them directly.  However some programming tasks (web apps / services) lend themselves to a seemingly more direct implementation if you use an event model directly, but you still need to manage all of that program state.   In order to track program logic across dispatches of several related events you have to manually track state and pass it around to the callbacks.  This tracking structure is usually called a state context or baton.  As you might imagine passing batons around all over the place to numerous seemingly unrelated handlers makes for some extremely hard to read and spaghetti-like code.  It's also a pain to write and debug -- especially when you're trying to handle the synchronization of various concurrent paths of execution.  You start getting into Futures and then the code becomes really difficult to read.

One well-known event processing library is call libuv.  It's a portable event loop that integrates Unix's reactor model with Windows' completion model into a single model usually called a "proactor".  Its the event handler that drives NodeJS.

Which brings us to communicating sequential processes.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes

Rather than writing asynchronous I/O dispatch and synchronization code using one or more concurrency models (and their often competing conventions), we flip the problem on its head.  We use a "coroutine" which looks like normal sequential code.

A simple example is a coroutine that receives a single byte over an event channel from another coroutine that sends a single byte.  This effectively synchronizes I/O producer and consumer because the writer/sender has to wait for a reader/receiver and vice-versa. While either process is waiting they explicitly yield execution to other processes.  When a coroutine yields, its scoped program state is saved on a stack frame thus saving you from the confusion of managing multi-layered baton state in an event loop.

Using applications built on these event channels we can construct arbitrary, reusable, concurrent logic and the algorithms no longer look like spaghetti code.  In pure CSP systems if you write to a channel and there is no reader, you will be blocked.  The channel endpoints are known via handles internally to the program.

Actor systems are different in a couple of ways.  First, the endpoints are the actor threads and they are named and known external to the mainline program.  The second difference is that sends and receives on these channels are buffered.  In other words if you send a message to an actor and there isn't one listening or its busy you aren't blocked until one reads from their input channel.  Other differences exist like one actor can publish to two different actors concurrently.

As you might guess Actor systems can easily be built from CSP systems.  There are other details like waiting for specific event patterns and selecting from them, but that's the basics.

I hope that clarifies things a bit.

Other constructs can be built from these ideas.  Various programming systems (Go, Erlang, etc) include CSP implementations within them.   Operating systems like Inferno and Node9 use CSPs and Channels as the basis of their distributed computing model.

Go: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(programming_language) 
Erlang: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language) 
Inferno: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_(operating_system) 
Node9: https://github.com/jvburnes/node9